# Custom Module Admin Grid Action not showing

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, uicomponent

I did a grid on my admin, but not showing the actions.
Can u help me?
[image]

Its my UI/component/listing/column actions.php file

```
<?php

namespace Test\Test\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;


class Actions extends Column
{

    const URL_PATH_EDIT = '[router_name]/[controller]/edit';
    const URL_PATH_DELETE = '[router_name]/[controller]/delete';
    const URL_PATH_DETAILS = '[router_name]/[controller]/details';


    protected $urlBuilder;


    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }


    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item['primary_id'])) {
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                        'edit' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_PATH_EDIT,
                                [
                                    'post_id' => $item['primary_id']
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Edit')
                        ],
                        'delete' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_PATH_DELETE,
                                [
                                    'post_id' => $item['primary_id']
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Delete'),
                            'confirm' => [
                                'title' => __('Delete "${ $.$data.title }"'),
                                'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a "${ $.$data.title }" record?')
                            ]
                        ]
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
```

its my .xml

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Test\test\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </listingToolbar>

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_test_test_listing.test_test_test_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">test_test_test_listing.test_test_test_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="nameOfDataSource">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">test_test_test_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="company_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Company</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Person</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn class="Test\Test\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions" name="actions">
    <settings>
        <indexField>post_id</indexField>
        <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
        <resizeDefaultWidth>107</resizeDefaultWidth>
    </settings>
</actionsColumn>

    </columns>
</listing>
```

I m waiting for ur answer!
Thanks

Comment: Are you using ui_composer for grid ?

Comment: i use ui_component

Comment: @IbrahimAldar please check my ans, it will help you to add actions in your custom grid

Comment: @IbrahimAldar just replace in Actions.php  $item[$this->getData('name')] with  $item[$this->getData('name')]['view']

Comment: its nottinh happend still i havent action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Action file is working fine

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {   if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            if (isset($item['post_id'])) {
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                    'view' => [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            static::URL_PATH_VIEW,
                            [
                                'partner' => $item['post_id']
                            ]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('View')
                    ],
                    'delete' => [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            static::URL_PATH_DELETE,
                            [
                                'partner' => $item['post_id']
                            ]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('Delete'),
                        'confirm' => [
                            'title' => __('Delete "${ $.$data.name }"'),
                            'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a "${ $.$data.name }" record?')
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
    }
```

Comment: What is that 'partner'? Can you explain that?

Comment: URL_PATH_VIEW = ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </listingToolbar>

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_test_test_listing.test_test_test_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">test_test_test_listing.test_test_test_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="nameOfDataSource">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">test_test_test_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="company_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Company</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Person</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn class="Test\Test\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions" name="actions">
    <settings>
        <indexField>post_id</indexField>
        <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
        <resizeDefaultWidth>107</resizeDefaultWidth>
    </settings>
</actionsColumn>

    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: please don't add multiple ans, if you want to add code in your question then click on edit link in your question and update your code over there.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your Actions.php , can you check this

```
<?php

namespace Test\Test\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Grid\Renderer\Action\UrlBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;


class Actions extends Column
{

    const URL_PATH_EDIT = '[router_name]/[controller]/edit';
    const URL_PATH_DELETE = '[router_name]/[controller]/delete';
    const URL_PATH_DETAILS = '[router_name]/[controller]/details';

    protected $actionUrlBuilder;
    protected $urlBuilder;
    private $editUrl;


    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        $editUrl = self::URL_PATH_EDIT
    )
    {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->actionUrlBuilder = $actionUrlBuilder;
        $this->editUrl = $editUrl;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }


    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $name = $this->getData('name');
                if (isset($item['primary_id'])) {
                    $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($this->editUrl, ['primary_id' => $item['primary_id']]),
                        'label' => __('Edit')
                    ];
                    $item[$name]['delete'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(self::URL_PATH_DELETE, ['primary_id' => $item['primary_id']]),
                        'label' => __('Delete'),
                        'confirm' => [
                            'title' => __('Delete ${ $.$data.title }'),
                            'message' => __('Do you wan\'t to delete a ${ $.$data.title } record?')
                        ]
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

> rm -r generated/*
>       rm -r pub/static/*
>
> ```
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> ```

Comment: still no changed